# Kendo UI - Tooltip reads only once

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

Given the sample of the Kendo UI to load a tooltip with ajax data.

```
 <ul id="products" class="dairy-photos">
    <li><a href="#" data-id="11">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/content/12.jpg")" /></a> </li>
</ul>

@(Html.Kendo().Tooltip()
.For("#products")
.Filter("a")
.LoadContentFrom("Details", "Tooltip")
.Position(TooltipPosition.Top)
.Width(220)
.Height(280)
.Events(events => events.RequestStart("requestStart")))

<script type="text/javascript">
    function requestStart(e) {
    e.options.data = {
        id: e.target.data("id")
    }
}
</script>
```

This is working fine, but the call to the Tooltip controller is made only once !?
I'm unable to find a way to make sure the call is made -every- time the tooltip is hovered. Any help on this one ?

Comment: It is actually an "optimization", they do not expect that a tooltip changes once displayed for the first time.

Comment: And there is no way to override this default "optimization" ? Depending on a textbox value, I want to show some server-side content.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is fixed in the latest release :
http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/tooltip/load-tooltip-content-via-ajax-everytime-it-opens.aspx

```
@(Html.Kendo().Tooltip()
//...
.Events(e =>
    {
       //...
        e.Show("show");          
    }))

<script type="text/javascript">
function show() {
    this.refresh();
}
```